# Question about Mayer-Vietoris sequence use

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Hatcher  defines the Mayer-Vietoris sequnece for a pair of subspaces $A,B \subset X$ such that $X$ is the union of the **interiors** of $A$ and $B$.

In his example 2.47 he decomposes the Klein bottle $K$ as the union of two Möbius bands $A$ and $B$ glued together by a homeomorphism of their boundary circles.

My problem with this is that I don't think $K$ is the union of the interiors of these Möbius bands.

> Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we tend to be rather liberal with the choice of $A \cup B$. Technically we must delete the boundary of these Möbius strips and stretch these a bit so they overlap (taking a neighborhood of each) then we can use a Mayer-Veitoris sequence. But this action of taking a small neighborhood just amounts to a new subspace that deformation retracts on to the old.